# mlton view intermediate C file when using `-codegen c`

Tags: sml, mlton

I have the following SML source file with a trivial function in it:

```
(* fact.sml *)
fun fact_unguarded 0 = 1
  | fact_unguarded n = n * fact_unguarded(n-1)

fun fact 0 = SOME(1)
  | fact n = if n > 0 then SOME(n * fact_unguarded(n-1)) else NONE
```

I'm trying to compile it with MLTon using the C backend and look at the generated C code.

```
% mlton -codegen c fact.sml
```

However, none of the intermediate files are dumped in the current working directory and there appears to be nothing relevant in `/tmp` either. Is there a way to direct MLTon to either a) produce just the C source file and stop or b) keep intermediate files around even after the final artifact is produced.

```
% pwd
~/tmp/sml
% ls
fact*       fact.sml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mlton -stop g -codegen c` should do what you want, but due to the way MLton works as a whole-program compiler, there will not be anything left of your functions.

Comment: And there is not. The code seems to be almost entirely stuff related to the MLTon runtime and magical comments describing the ML-side compiler options.